# Using svg with jest in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jestjs

I'm using jest for testing in react and i'm using svg but while running test i'm getting error
**

Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module '/assets/icons/AscendingIcon.svg' from 'src/assets.js'

Require stack:
  src/assets.js
  src/common/form/FormikInputArray.jsx
  src/common/form/FormikControl.jsx
  src/common/index.js
  src/components/project/ProjectTable.jsx
  src/components/project/test/ProjectTable.test.jsx

  1 | /* exporting all the assets for consumption */
> 2 | export { default as AscendingIcon } from "/assets/icons/AscendingIcon.svg";
    | ^
  3 | export { default as CheckIcon } from "/assets/icons/CheckIcon.svg";
  4 | export { default as ChevronDownIcon } from "/assets/icons/ChevronDownIcon.svg";
  5 | export { default as ChevronRightIcon } from "/assets/icons/ChevronRightIcon.svg";
```

**
in my src/assets.js :- i've exported svg like this from assests.js

```
export { default as AscendingIcon } from "/assets/icons/AscendingIcon.svg";
```

and in /assets/icons/AscendingIcon.svg

```
<svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M9 4.5L5.98967 1.5M5.98967 1.5L3 4.5M5.98967 1.5L5.98967 10.5007" stroke="#B3A0BA" stroke-linecap="round"
    stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
```

i don't have any idea about it.
here is my folder

[image]

Comment: could you post file (src) structure to your question?

Comment: don't post like this even no one could understand it well, try to post a screen shot of it.

Comment: @nuser137 i've added the screenshot

Comment: as you said `i've imported file like this  export { default as AscendingIcon } from "/assets/icons/AscendingIcon.svg";` I guess you would want to write `import` instead of `export`.

Comment: yes! sorry for that

Comment: @nuser137 i've exported svg from assets.js file which i've imported in my components like this
`import { AscendingIcon, DescendingIcon } from "src/assets";
`